# How to rewrite only one certain URL to the same path on another domain with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, prerender

I'm trying to run one certain page of the site through prerender.io service.

If i use `RewriteRule` as `RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,END]` it works like a charm, BUT for all URLs.

If i edit this rule to `RewriteRule /folder/page.html https://service.prerender.io/%https://%example.com/folder/page.html [P,END]` i run into 5xx error.

What should it be done on the right way?

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^folder/page\.html$ https://service.prerender.io/https://example.com/folder/page.html [P,END]`

Comment: You should read a bit in the documentation of the tools you are using. There you will find out that a `RewriteRule` always operates on a _relative path_ component, not an absolute, if used in the context of per-directory configurations.

Comment: Did you really just try to replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` with `%example.com`? The `%{…}` syntax is used to insert variable values, if you are replacing that with a static value, then you need to remove not only the curly braces, but also the percent sign.